# Django Rest Framework Nested Serializer required=False error

Tags: django-rest-framework

In DRF v3.1, I have a nested serializer much like the one detailed in the docs - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

```
class SerializerA(serializers.Serializer):
    details = DetailsSerializer(required=False)
```

However, when trying to use this serializer and not supplying the details, I receive the following:

```
{u'details': [u'This field may not be null.']}
```

This seems incorrect given the docs?

Has anyone else come across this or can verify this as a bug?

Comment: What is the relevant output of `repr(SerializerA())`? You probably want to set `allow_null` for `DetailsSerializer`.

Comment: Hi, the output is `SerializerA():
    details = DetailsSerializer(required=False):
        a = CharField(max_length=100, min_length=1, required=True)`

Comment: Also, according to the docs, If a nested representation may optionally accept the None value you should pass the required=False flag to the nested serializer. To me this means I don't require the allow_null param?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Ok, so Kevin Browns comment is correct. I needed to add allow_null=True.

```
class SerializerA(serializers.Serializer):
    details = DetailsSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)
```

The reason for this is that having required=False allows the field details to be absent from the data when constructing the serializer.

e.g.
`s = SerializerA(data={})`

whereas allow_null permits the the param to be specified but be null.

e.g. 
`s = SerializerA(data={'details': None})`

This opens up another issue with DRF Browsable API, but i'll ask that in a different question.

Comment: Man I'm struggling with this error for a couple of hours. Thanks! By the way, where can I find this serializer docs?

Comment: If you have a 1:N relation, setting required=False is not enough. You have to pass many=true to the serializer. 
```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = ContactSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```
Got here through Google, so I hope, someone will read this comment