# Django Serializers: multiple tables OneToOne relation to a table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-serializer

This is Django ORM models

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.Foreignkey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.Foreignkey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here are the serializers:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = A

class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = ASerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = B

class CSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = ASerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = C
```

B and C are working as expected.

Problem 1:

Now, if I want to get data of B and C from serializer A by doing `b = BSerializer(many=False)` and `c = CSerializer(many=False)`. I will get an error that `NameError: name 'BSerializer' is not defined` and if I put B and C serializer above A errors for Aserializer. How do I fix this?

Problem 2:

B and C have one-to-one relation with A. So, when serializing A, it might not have a subsequent B or C or both data in B and C tables.
So, in ASerializer

```
b = BSerializer(many=False)
c = CSerializer(many=False)
```

might give errors if there is no relation between A and C for a particular row. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest that if you are intending to have a [one-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/), that you actually define it that way:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**PROBLEM ONE**

I have not tested this yet, but could it be a definitional order issue? What happens if you place the definition of `class A` after `class B` and `class C`?

**PROBLEM TWO**

Try adding `required=False, allow_null=True` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606115/django-rest-framework-nested-serializer-required-false-error).

```
b = BSerializer(many=False, required=False, allow_null=True)
c = CSerializer(many=False, required=False, allow_null=True)
```

Comment: Adding definition of A after B and C would still give the error because B and C are using A.

Comment: Hmm, well you could try something real hacky, by adding another serializer class at the end that just subclasses A: `class HackyClassA(A):  pass`